# Using regex with JUnit

Tags: java, regex, junit

I've setup a unit test for a Java application that calls a web service.  This web service returns a JSON string.  Let's assume the following samples

```
{
"id": 2,
"time": "1346",
"user": {
    "firstname": "foo",
    "lastname": "bar",
    "email": "foo@bar.com"
  }
}

class GetUserImpl implements GetUser {
  public String getUserDetails() {
    return new MyWebService().getUserDetaild(];
  }
}

class Example Test {
  @Test
  public testGetUserDetails() {
    assertEquals(new GetUserImpl().getUserDetails(), regex);
  }
}
```

How would I use junit to test the following:

- Is the ID a number, I don't care what the value is as long as it's not null and equal to or greater than 0
- Is the time a valid format, regardless of the value
- Is the email a valid email format, regardless of the value

Comment: I assume you own and not just use that web service, otherwise it wouldn't be your job to test the (hopefully stable) API.

Comment: Correct, I own the web service.  I guess another way to put it is this.  I need to test the schema is as expected and a second test to make sure the format of the values are valid.

Comment: I wouldnt use assertEquals here, but assertThat and probably a custom matcher.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would prefer to break up your conditions into 3 different Assert statements and possible even 3 different tests and not try no lump all three requirements into one regex:

```
public void userIDShouldBeNonNullPositiveInteger()
public void userTimeShouldHaveValidTimeFormat()
public void userEmailShouldHaveValidFormat()
```

Also, agree with @GhostCat, that one good way to write these 3 tests is to have [customMatchers](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/11/custom-hamcrest-matchers.html) for each. So, you could do something like this for the first test above:

```
public class PositiveIntegerMatcher extends TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher<Integer> {
   @Override
   protected boolean matchesSafely(String idStr, Description description) {
       if (StringUtils.isNumeric(idStr) && isPositive(idStr) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void describeTo(Description description) {

   }
}
```

This is some example code. Note, that I am using the [apache commons (3)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) library to make things easy on myself, and I have not completed all of the code for you.

By breaking up this test into three tests, you will make your code much more readable and your intention clearer.